# How to use CustomJS to update a scatter plot in Bokeh

Tags: javascript, bokeh

I have a length and weight of multiple specimens of many species of butterflies (common_name) and I would like to make a dynamic graph in Bokeh where the user can select a given species to display a scatterplot of the lengths and weights. The dataframe is a simple 4 columns dataframe with 4 variables: `length`, `weight`, `common_name` and `size`. There are hundreds of entries (i.e each specimen has a common_name, lenght and weight). The size is always 10 so I can set it to 0 in the callback. A simplified version of my code looks like so:

```
def scatter_plot(request):

  butterfly_data = pd.DataFrame(butterfly_data)

  source = ColumnDataSource( butterfly_data)


  ### Main plot
  plot = figure(title='Length-weight relationship', x_axis_label='length (cm)', y_axis_label='weight (g)',
         tools="pan, hover, box_zoom, reset, save", toolbar_location="below",
         plot_width=400, plot_height=400)

  plot.circle(x='length', y='weight', source=source, line_width=2) 

  # List of species
  available_species = list(set(butterfly_data['common_name']))
  available_species.sort()

  # Species selection widget
  callback99 = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source), code="""
    var data = source.data;
    var inpt = cb_obj.active;
    var size = data['size'];
    var common_name = data['common_name'];

    for (var i = 0; i < size.length; i++) {
        var ret = [];

        for (var a = 0; a < inpt.length; a++) {

            for (var z = 0; z < common_name[i].length; z++) {
                console.log("ret", common_name, ret, common_name[i], "s", inpt[a], size.length);

            }
        }

        if (ret.length == 0) {
            size[i] = 0;
            } else {
            size[i] = 10;
        }
    }
    source.change.emit();
""")

  species_selection = CheckboxGroup(labels=available_species, active = [])
  species_selection.js_on_change('active', callback99)

  # Set up widgets layout
  widgets_layout = column(species_selection)

  # Set up figures layout
  figures_layout = row(plot)

  # Set up page layout
  page_layout = row(widgets_layout, figures_layout)

  script, div = components(page_layout)
  return render_to_response('scatter.html', {'script':script, 'div':div})
```

My problem is that I cant get the scatterplot to update (nothing happens when I select a given species). I must have fumbled the callback.

Any ideas ?

Comment: This part: `data['common_name']=data[cb_obj.value]` is definitely not useful for updating the plot, but it's not really possible to speculate further without information about the structure of the dataframe and what's in it.

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is essentially a simpler version of the application here: https://machineloveus.com/visualizing-bird-feed-and-feeders-with-bokeh/

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this (Bokeh v1.1.0):

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, CustomJS, CheckboxGroup, Column

butterfly_data = dict(length = [1, 2, 3], weight = [10, 20, 30], common_name = ['butterfly1', 'butterfly2', 'butterfly3'], size = [100, 100, 100])
butterfly_data = pd.DataFrame(butterfly_data)

butterfly_source = ColumnDataSource(butterfly_data)
source = ColumnDataSource(dict(length = [], weight = [], common_name = [], size = []))

plot = figure(title = 'Length-Weight Relationship', x_axis_label = 'length (cm)', y_axis_label = 'weight (g)',
       tools = "pan, hover, box_zoom, reset, save", toolbar_location = "right")
plot.circle(x = 'length', y = 'weight', source = source, line_width = 2)

species_selection = CheckboxGroup(labels = list(butterfly_data['common_name'].values), active = [])

callback = CustomJS(args = dict(source = source, species_selection = species_selection, butterfly_source = butterfly_source), code = """
    var data = { length: [], weight: [], common_name: [], size: [] };
    var selected_indexes = cb_obj.active;
    for (var i = 0; i < selected_indexes.length; i++) {
        index = selected_indexes[i];
        data['length'].push(butterfly_source.data['length'][index]);
        data['weight'].push(butterfly_source.data['weight'][index]);
        data['common_name'].push(butterfly_source.data['common_name'][index]);
        data['size'].push(butterfly_source.data['size'][index]);
    }
    source.data = data; """)

species_selection.js_on_change('active', callback)

page_layout = Column(species_selection, plot)

show(page_layout)
```

[image]

Comment: Almost. I mean your code does work but the problem is that you get one checkbox for each specimen. If you have 3 butterfly3, you'll have 3 checkbox butterfly3. How would link the checkbox to the species, not to the specimen ?

Comment: Sorry, but given the title of your question + "nothing happens when I select a given species" then I did exactly what you asked. There was no species or specimens in your data, just a `common_name` so I took the `common_name` as the species names. And if `common_name` stands for `specimens` data then where is info about `species`? How can one model and plot data that is missing? So you need more checkboxes for species? Maybe it would be a good idea to post another question and add a paper drawing how you want to have it (e.g. which checkboxes for species and another checkboxes for specimens?)

Comment: My apologies, I didn’t mean to be unclear. Let’s say we have data that look like so:   
'butterfly_data = dict(length = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], weight = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 10, 25], common_name = ['species1', 'species1', 'species2', 'species2', 'species3', 'species3', 'species3'])'
'butterfly_data = pd.DataFrame(butterfly_data)'

Comment: I would like to create a checkbox widget with 3 checkboxes (1 for each species: species1, species2 and species3) so that when the user click on a given checkbox (say species 1) only the lengths and weights associated with that species are displayed on the scatterplot. I hope this is clearer. Thank you for your time, much obliged.